# Linq's DataContexts and "Unit of Work" pattern. Is my approach ok?

Tags: linq-to-sql, design-patterns, datacontext, webforms, unit-of-work

Following the directions from many articles, I've decided to implement the `Unit of work` pattern to my `Linq2SQL DataContexts` in my `ASP.Net WebForms Application`, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right way.

Here's what I'm accomplishing so far:

1 - On every `Request`, I catch the `Application_AcquireRequestState` event (which has access to Session data) in `Global.asax` and instantiate a new `DataContext` to bind it to the user's `Session`:

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the request is for a Page, Page Method or Handler
    if (new Regex(@"\.(aspx|ashx)(/.*)?$").IsMatch(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath))
    {
        MyCompany.MyDatabaseDataContext myDatabaseDataContext = new MyCompany.MyDatabaseDataContext();

        HttpContext.Current.Session["myDatabaseDataContext"] = myDatabaseDataContext;
    }
}
```

2 - Every `Data Access Layer` Object (DAO) inherits from a base `DAO`: `GenericDAO`:

```
public class GenericDAO
{
    private MyDatabaseDataContext _dbMyDatabase;

    protected MyDatabaseDataContext dbMyDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dbMyDatabase == null)
                _dbMyDatabase = HttpContext.Current.Session["myDatabaseDataContext"] as MyDatabaseDataContext;

            return _dbMyDatabase;
        }
    }
}
```

3 - So, in every operation, the `DAO` use the `DataContext` Property from its parent class:

```
public class MyTableDAO : GenericDAO
{
    public List<MyTable> getAll()
    {
        return dbMyDatabase.GetTable<MyTable>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Here's my concerns...

1. First of all, is it ok to store the `DataContext` in the user's Session? What would be another option? **My app has a lot of PageMethods calls**, so I'm worried the DTX would be invalidated between their async requests if it is stored in the session.
2. Do I need to capture the `Application_ReleaseRequestState` event to `Dispose()` of the `DataContext` and remove it from the session?
3. If I don't need to Dispose of it, in every `Application_AcquireRequestState`, would it be better to `Remove DTX from Session - Create DTX - Store it` or just `Refresh` it?
4. Also, if I don't need to Dispose of it, what about `Connections`? Would it handle them automatically or I would need to control them too?

I appreciate your time and help :)

-- EDIT

Here's the code I've reached, following @ivowiblo's suggestion:

**Global.asax**

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (new Regex(@"\.(aspx|ashx)(/.*)?$").IsMatch(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath))
    {
        MyCompany.MyDatabaseDataContext myDatabaseDataContext = new MyCompany.MyDatabaseDataContext();

        HttpContext.Current.Items["myDatabaseDataContext"] = ceabsDataContext;
    }
}

void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (new Regex(@"\.(aspx|ashx)(/.*)?$").IsMatch(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath))
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["myDatabaseDataContext"] != null)
        {
            System.Data.Linq.DataContext myDbDtx = HttpContext.Current.Items["myDatabaseDataContext"] as System.Data.Linq.DataContext;

            if (myDbDtx != null)
                myDbDtx.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**GenericDAO**

```
public class GenericDAO
{
    protected MyDatabaseDataContext dbMyDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Items["myDatabaseDataContext"] as MyDatabaseDataContext;
        }
    }
}
```

Simple as that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to put it on `HttpContext.Current.Items`, creating the DataContext on `RequestBegin` and dispose it in `RequestEnd`. In [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/04/27/lifetime-of-a-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx) there's an interesting article about the better management of the DataContext, where it's suggested to have short-time DataContext instances.

This pattern is called `Open session in view` and was created for using NHibernate in web environments.

Comment: Thank you very much... I've implemented as you suggested and I'm very satisfied with the results so far. Tomorrow at work I'll update the question with the final code to help anothers in future researches :)

Answer (score 1):

You say you are implementing unit-of-work, but by storing it in the cache you do not really stick to that unit-of-work.

My advice is to create a new DataContext for **every** request and not to cache it anyware.

Comment: No, as I said, the above code is what I accomplished so far. See my concerns #2 and #3, they are the points I have left to implement it correctly as a unit of work.

Comment: Also, as it is right now, every request creates a new DTX and store it to the session. In a unsafe way, it's already working as a unit of work (except for async calls, that could end in weird results).

Comment: The best approach is to put it on HttpContext.Current.Items, creating the DataContext on RequestBegin and dispose it in RequestEnd. In http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/04/27/lifetime-of-a-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx there's an interesting article about the better management of the DataContext, where it's suggested to have short-time DataContext instances.

Comment: Interesting way to avoid Session use... Well @ivowiblo, it seems to be the best answer so far... do you mind putting it up on an real answer? Thanks!